# Django: passing an entire object in rest api

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, django, rest

I'm working with Django and I'm creating an api following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) tutorial.

What I find extremely hard to understand is how to create an api for posting big amount of data (in other words can I pass an object and not parameters),

For example if I like to pass data to a view that saves a user object to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    UserUniqueID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    NickName VARCHAR (20) NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber2 VARCHAR (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE  NULL,
    UserAvatar BYTEA NULL,
    AboutMe VARCHAR (500) NULL, 
    MemberSince TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    UserType INTEGER NULL,
    UserScore INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

what would be the url like and how can I pass an entire object? 
Important: the call to this service is done from iOS native mobile application.

Comment: Do you want to pass data using ajax?

Comment: No I'll be calling the service from an IOS mobile app

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the Django Rest Framework. With it, you can easily set serializers for your models, that will handle all the information coming from the iOS requests. Django Rest Framework use Class Based Views and another nice Django tools.

Take a look, they has a nice documentation.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/